# How to read temperature from ti SensorTag Android

Tags: android, sensors, texas-instruments

I'm developing an android app that reads data from Texas Instruments SensorTag CC2650.

I'm able to discover BLe device, connect to one of these and finally get battery value of the SensorTag. But I don't kow how get the value of temperature by the specific sensor.

For the battery I take the specific service next the characteristic and finally I run the command:

```
BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(...)
```

For temperature I've read that I have to turn on the sensor first, next I must enable the notification and finally I can get the value on the method `onCharacteristicChanged` of the callback.

Can someone give me the code for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be very useful with the old SensorTag 1)   http://evothings.com/quick-guide-to-making-a-mobile-app-for-the-ti-sensortag-using-javascript/